# Get a Username from another Process

Tags: .net, dll, process, running-other-programs

im am actually programming a tool for a AntiCheat detection because the publisher it self don´t interested in that to create one. It is almost done the Only one thing we need is to Verify the Username and to get it from the client to verify it with registred users from our community. ToDo this we need to read The Username from the specific Process Coded with QT5 Engine.

Only Read is needed nothing more.

I´ll tried before with screen scraping but it doesn´t help because it is only usefull for a website.

Also done a Memory Scan of the Program and didn´t give the exact result.

Maybe you guys can help me out with a little trick?!?

Program is Coded in C# and got a client and server version but Client do CRC32 checks and Memory scan´s.

cheers

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @ Hans Passant but can you explain it more detailed for me pls? maybe with a codessnippet explaination? thnx

Comment: maybe it help if i told you i need the Username of the Origin.exe also named Origin ID